# What kind of display magic is this? Monitor shows picture only for few seconds

Tags: display

I have one (very)old display, and after system is started it shows picture for two seconds and than again went dead. And every time I turn monitor on/off it shows picture for 2 seconds.
Normal picture from OS! Not logo, or something like that!

It is an old [LG flatron 1510S](http://www.lg.com/levant_en/support-product/lg-FLATRON-L1510S#). I have switched cables, VGA and power, but still the same.

edit: Other monitors works just fine on that PC (it is not PC issue, that LG does the same thing on every machine)

Comment: Do other monitors work with your computer, or is it all monitors that do the same? We need to rule out whether it's a graphics card or a monitor problem...

Comment: Then, by process of elimination, you have discovered the LG is broken. It's probably not worth the cost of repair; recycle it & buy a new one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's an old monitor you most likely have a problem with capacitors and inverter that powers it's back-light. On old LCD monitors there are cold cathode fluorescent tubes that provide back-light, unlike new LED type monitors.

Try shining a strong light directly on the display and see if you get a glimpse of image. If you do - you have a back-light problem and fixing it is not a good option, as it costs more than your monitor is worth (around 30-40$ where I'm from).

If you can't see any trace of image you may have problems with underlying electronics, so you should really recycle it.

Comment: Puno hvala! You were right, when I point light on display I could see some fade image. I dont know how much does it costs it should be the same as where you come from ;)  but I was wondering what the problem was. So Enis, thanks a lot.